# Why is Keras complaining about incompatible input shape in this case?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a Keras-based autoencoder model with the following input layer:

```
depth = 1
width = height = 100
input_shape = (height, width, depth)
inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
# rest of network definition ...
```

Width and height of my training images were 100 pixels in grayscale, thus with a depth of 1. Now I want to load my trained model in another script, load an image there, resize and send it to the Keras model:

```
size = 100
image = cv2.imread(args.image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = cv2.resize(image, (size, size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
image = image.astype("float32") / 255.0
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)
# at this point image.shape = (100, 100, 1)
recon = autoencoder.predict(image)
```

However, the call to `autoencoder.predict(image)` leads to the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 100, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 100, 1, 1).
```

I don't understand this, as the shape of the image when calling `predict()` is `(100, 100, 1)`, which looks fine to me. Why is Keras complaining about an incompatible input shape of `(None, 100, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These simple lines of code generate the error

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (100,100,1))

inp = Input((100,100,1))
out = Dense(1)(Flatten()(inp))
model = Model(inp, out)

model.predict(X)
```

This is because your Keras model expects data in this format `(n_sample, 100, 100, 1)`

A simple reshape when you predict a single image does the trick

```
model.predict(X.reshape(1,100,100,1))
```