# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 1024, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

i have an error from my predict code in image processing the machine learning, this is my code

```
# load the trained model
model = load_model('./model/modelLeNet5.h5')
x=(img1/255)

# predict the input image using the loaded model
pred1 = model.predict_classes(x)
```

the error says :

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the
> layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received:
> (None, 1024, 3)

Comment: You need some preprocessing steps on `img1` of yours.

Comment: what is the shape of your image? normally it is like (224,22,3) usually to put an image into model.predict you have to do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921717/10375049

Comment: The dataset will be of shape  `[batch, w, h, channel]`. You need add batch axis to your test data. Reshape your input image x as something like `x =  x.reshape(-1,28,28,1)`.